# How to batch zip an image directory plus one js and one html file, Win 7

Tags: windows, zip

I would like to do a batch zip file operation. What each zip file has in common is an images directory and a *.js and a *.html file with the same name.

Comment: Why not use 7zip? It has a pretty nice command line interface...

Comment: Thanks, each folder needs 11 zips created. How does one tell the program to choose an image directory plus make a zip of each of 11 pairs of files with the same name, but different extensions.

Answer (score 0):

7zip has a pretty neat [command line interface](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline) (which is also part of the 7zip documentation; see http://7-zip.org for more information) which can be used within a .bat file to create archives of any complexity.

For a start try the following batch file (e.g. save as generate.bat). It will loop over all subdirectories of the working directory and add all files of the subdirectories within its own .zip file named as the subdirectory. After that the corresponding .js and .html files are added to the archive.

```
@echo off

SET SEVENZIP=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
:: if 7z.exe is available within your PATH the following is sufficient: SET SEVENZIP=7z.exe

:: remember initial (current) directory
SET INITIAL_DIR=%CD%

:: define working directory
SET WORKING_DIR=%1
IF "%WORKING_DIR%" == "" (
   ECHO No input directory given using current directory...
   SET WORKING_DIR=%INITIAL_DIR%
)


:: change to working directory
CHDIR /D "%WORKING_DIR%"

:: loop over sub-directories
for /D %%a in (*) do (
    ECHO.
    ECHO.
    ECHO *** Creating %%a.zip ***

    :: add all files within images directory with name %%a
    "%SEVENZIP%" a "%%a.zip" "%%a\*"

    :: add .js and .html file
    "%SEVENZIP%" a "%%a.zip" "%%a.js"
    "%SEVENZIP%" a "%%a.zip" "%%a.html"
)

:: change back to original directory
CHDIR /D "%INITIAL_DIR%"


:end
ECHO.
ECHO.
PAUSE
```

To run it either copy it to your working directory or use the Windows Explorer and drag 'n' drop the working directory onto the .bat file.